# Why does enabled SeRestorePrivilege allow for READ_CONTROL access to a file

Tags: windows, acl, privileges, elevated-privileges

According to [Windows API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privilege-constants),

SeBackupPrivilege

> causes the system to grant all read access control to any file, regardless of the access control list (ACL) specified for the file. Any access request other than read is still evaluated with the ACL. The following access rights are granted if this privilege is held: READ_CONTROL,
>   ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_TRAVERSE

SeRestorePrivilege:

> causes the system to grant all write access control to any file, regardless of the ACL specified for the file. Any access request other than write is still evaluated with the ACL. The following access rights are granted if this privilege is held: WRITE_DAC, WRITE_OWNER, ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_ADD_FILE, FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY, DELETE

I noticed, however, that if a process token has SeRestorePrivilege, opening a file with `READ_CONTROL` succeeds. Why is it so?

Code:

```
import os
import sys

import ntsecuritycon
import win32con
import win32file
import win32security
import win32api


def print_token_info():
    tok = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), win32security.TOKEN_QUERY)
    sid, attr = win32security.GetTokenInformation(tok, win32security.TokenUser)
    name, domain, sid_name_use = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, sid)
    print(f"User: {name}@{domain}")

    sid = win32security.GetTokenInformation(tok, win32security.TokenOwner)
    name, domain, sid_name_use = win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, sid)
    print(f"Owner of new files: {name}@{domain}")

    privileges = win32security.GetTokenInformation(tok, win32security.TokenPrivileges)
    print("Privileges")
    priv_attr_flags = {
        win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED: 'SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED',
        win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT: 'SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT',
        win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED: 'SE_PRIVILEGE_REMOVED',
        win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS: 'SE_PRIVILEGE_USED_FOR_ACCESS',
    }
    for luid, attr in privileges:
        priv_name = win32security.LookupPrivilegeName(None, luid)
        flag_str = []
        for flag in priv_attr_flags:
            if (attr & flag) == flag:
                flag_str.append(priv_attr_flags[flag])
        print(f"- {priv_name} -> {attr} ({', '.join(flag_str)})")
    win32api.CloseHandle(tok)


def disable_privilege(privilege_name):
    print(f"Disabling privilege {privilege_name}")

    tok = win32security.OpenProcessToken(
        win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY
    )
    luid = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, privilege_name)
    se_privilege_disabled = 0
    new_state = [(luid, se_privilege_disabled)]
    win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(tok, 0, new_state)
    win32api.CloseHandle(tok)


def enable_privilege(privilege_name):
    print(f"Enabling privilege {privilege_name}")

    tok = win32security.OpenProcessToken(
        win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY
    )
    luid = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, privilege_name)
    new_state = [(luid, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
    win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(tok, 0, new_state)
    win32api.CloseHandle(tok)


def open_handle(path):
    try:
        handle = win32file.CreateFileW(
            path,
            ntsecuritycon.READ_CONTROL,
            0,
            None,
            win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
            win32file.FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT | win32file.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            None,
        )
        handle.Close()
        print(f"Successfully opened {path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to open {path}: {e}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = sys.argv[1]

    with open(path, "w") as fo:
        pass

    dacl = win32security.ACL()
    dacl.SetEntriesInAcl([])
    win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo(
        path,
        win32security.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
        win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | win32security.PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        None,
        None,
        dacl,
        None,
    )

    print_token_info()
    open_handle(path)
    print()

    enable_privilege(win32security.SE_BACKUP_NAME)
    # print_token_info()
    open_handle(path)
    print()

    disable_privilege(win32security.SE_BACKUP_NAME)
    # print_token_info()
    open_handle(path)
    print()

    enable_privilege(win32security.SE_RESTORE_NAME)
    # print_token_info()
    open_handle(path)
    print()

    disable_privilege(win32security.SE_RESTORE_NAME)
    # print_token_info()
    open_handle(path)
    print()
```

Output on elevated console:

```
> python .\test_access.py C:\tmp\test\file-10
User: dev@CBIT-02
Owner of new files: Administrators@BUILTIN
Privileges
- SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeSecurityPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeLoadDriverPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeSystemProfilePrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeSystemtimePrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeCreatePagefilePrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeBackupPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeRestorePrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeShutdownPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeDebugPrivilege -> 2 (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)
- SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeChangeNotifyPrivilege -> 3 (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT)
- SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeUndockPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeManageVolumePrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeImpersonatePrivilege -> 3 (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT)
- SeCreateGlobalPrivilege -> 3 (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT)
- SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeTimeZonePrivilege -> 0 ()
- SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege -> 2 (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)
- SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege -> 0 ()
Failed to open C:\tmp\test\file-10: (5, 'CreateFileW', 'Access is denied.')

Enabling privilege SeBackupPrivilege
Successfully opened C:\tmp\test\file-10

Disabling privilege SeBackupPrivilege
Failed to open C:\tmp\test\file-10: (5, 'CreateFileW', 'Access is denied.')

Enabling privilege SeRestorePrivilege
Successfully opened C:\tmp\test\file-10

Disabling privilege SeRestorePrivilege
Failed to open C:\tmp\test\file-10: (5, 'CreateFileW', 'Access is denied.')
```

Comment: The file-specific access constants are [listed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants).  Note that you probably meant to test for FILE_READ_DATA and FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, READ_CONTROL only provides read access to the security descriptor.

Comment: I specifically mean READ_CONTROL. GENERIC_READ, for instance, works as expected. But the documentation doesn't mention READ_CONTROL in SeRestorePrivilege.

Comment: Thanks Eryk. 
Also found nice summary of access masks: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170310-00/?p=95705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the question, SeRestorePrivilege with backup semantics grants the following rights: `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY`, `WRITE_DAC`, `WRITE_OWNER`, `DELETE`, `FILE_ADD_FILE`, `FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY`, and `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE`.

`FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` is the access mask that gets mapped to `GENERIC_WRITE` access for a file object. It includes `READ_CONTROL`, `SYNCHRONIZE`, `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` (0x0100), `FILE_WRITE_EA` (0x0010) , `FILE_APPEND_DATA` (0x0004), and `FILE_WRITE_DATA` (0x0002). Note that last two are the same value as `FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY` (0x0004) and `FILE_ADD_FILE` (0x0002), so the documentation of SeRestorePrivilege is redundant.

The `READ_CONTROL` right in the mask comes from `STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE`. Most generic access masks include one of the following standard-rights masks:

```
STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ     = READ_CONTROL
STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE    = READ_CONTROL
STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE  = READ_CONTROL
STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC | WRITE_OWNER | DELETE
```

The above all include the `READ_CONTROL` right, which ensures that requesting generic access includes the right to query the discretionary and mandatory security of an object.

---

Note that your experiment also needs to control for implicit owner rights. If a file's owner is the requesting user or one of the user's enabled groups, then the user is implicitly granted `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` access. You can control for this either by ensuring the file is owned by a different security principle, such as "SYSTEM", or by adding an ACE for the "OWNER_RIGHTS" security principle that grants no access, which overrides implicit owner rights.

Note also that `CreateFile` implicitly requests `SYNCHRONIZE` and `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access, even if `dwDesiredAccess` is 0. SeRestorePrivilege does not grant `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access. In your experiment, this right must have been granted by filesystem policy. Regardless of a file's security descriptor, a user is granted the right to read attributes if the user has `FILE_READ_DATA` (i.e. `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY`) access to the parent directory. This makes the file API consistent because most file metadata (e.g. file attributes, timestamps and size) can be obtained by listing the parent directory. To control your experiment, you need to use a directory that does not grant the user read-data access. Then you will observe that SeRestorePrivilege by itself does not enable `CreateFile` to succeed.